# how to create a function with optional parameter python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a plotting function to plot some data. I would like to syntax it in a way that it will automatically get y limits,EXCEPT when I manually want to pass specific limits to it.

I have done that by manually changing the value in a variable,when i want my own axis limits to be used. However I understand that this is just a work around, so any suggestions are welcome:

```
def plot_data(dataset, set_own_lim=1, my_ymin, my_ymax):
       ax=plt.subplot(111)
             if set_own_lim=0:
                ax.set_ylim(min(dataset),max(dataset)) #calculating y range from data
             else:
                ax.set_ylim(my_ymin, my_ymax)        # uses my own limits for y range
       ax.plot(dataset)
```

I would like to define a function in a way, that I could call it like `plot_data(some_data)` to get automatic limits from data and I could also call it as `plot_data(some_data,my_ymin, my_ymax)`, when i need to define the axis range manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `my_ymin, my_ymax` arguments are `None` and inside the function you can put a check if these values are `None` then you can calculate them otherwise use the values passed by the user. Like so:

```py
def plot_data(dataset, my_ymin=None, my_ymax=None):
       ax=plt.subplot(111)
             if not my_ymin:
                ax.set_ylim(min(dataset),max(dataset))
             else:
                ax.set_ylim(my_ymin, my_ymax)
       ax.plot(dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler use of `None`:

```
def plot_data(dataset, ymin=None, ymax=None):
   # ...
   ymin = min(dataset) if ymin is None else ymin
   ymax = max(dataset) if ymax is None else ymax
   # ...
```

Keep in mind however, that this would disable you from *actually* passing `None` to `set_XXXlim()`.   In that case, you can use a sentinel value:

```
sentinel = object()

def plot_data(dataset, ymin=sentinel, ymax=sentinel):
   # ...
   ymin = min(dataset) if ymin is sentinel else ymin
   ymax = max(dataset) if ymax is sentinel else ymax
   # ...
```

which will permit `plot_data(data, None, None)`.